# Apache storm spout emit speed faster than bolts computing causing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: apache-storm, concurrentmodification

Here is my situation. I have a kafka spout and the spout per second emit a tuple. The bolt will connect to Rserve and need about 5 seconds to compute the result then emit a tuple.
But the bolt always get ConcurrentModificationException then the worker die!

```
public class LagBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

OutputCollector _collector;

public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector outputCollector) {
    _collector = outputCollector;
}

public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    List<Pair> pairs = (List<Pair>) tuple.getValueByField("pairs");
    double[] value = new double[pairs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
        value[i] = pairs.get(i).getValue();
    }

    Model model = new Model();
    RConnection rConnection = new RserveConnection().getrConnection();

    // the test() and estimate() need about five seconds to compute
    int d = model.test(rConnection, value);
    int[] ap = model.estimate(rConnection, value, d);
    List<Parameter> parameters = delegate(ap, d);
    rConnection.close();

    _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(parameters));
    _collector.ack(tuple);
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("parameters"));
}

private List<Parameter> delegate(int[] ap, int d){
    int apNum = ap[0];
    List<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

    for(int i = 1; i < 1+apNum; i++){
        for(int j = apNum+1; j < ap.length; j++){
            Parameter parameter = new Parameter(ap[i], d, ap[j]);
            parameters.add(parameter);
        }
    }

    return parameters;
}
```

***This is exception***

379632 [Thread-14-Lag] ERROR b.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:135) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1049) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1045) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:450) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:458) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.toString(TupleImpl.java:222) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.core$str.invoke(core.clj:520) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$str$fn__3928.invoke(core.clj:524) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$str.doInvoke(core.clj:526) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:516) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:693) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        ... 6 more
379677 [Thread-14-Lag] ERROR b.s.d.executor -
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:135) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1049) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1045) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:450) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:458) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.toString(TupleImpl.java:222) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.core$str.invoke(core.clj:520) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$str$fn__3928.invoke(core.clj:524) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$str.doInvoke(core.clj:526) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:516) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:693) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        ... 6 more

Comment: What do you do in your method `delegate`, when you get the parameter list? Take a look to [this](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Troubleshooting.html), look for `ConcurrentModificationException`. Is it possible that your process is modifying the parameters while `storm` is serializing?

Comment: Hi!  lrnzcig, thanks for answering me back. I read the Troubleshooting. I'm not sure and don't understand what situation will let my process modify the parameter while storm is serializing. I add the delegate function code in the post.

Comment: If I don't connect Rserve to compute the result, I give "d" and "ap" default values like d = 2 and ap = {3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}. The ConcurrentModificationException is never happened. This is why I think the spout emit speed faster than bolt computeing speed causing the exception.
This is confusing me because if bolt can't keep up the spout emit speed, the tuple should be buffered until idle executor to process.

Comment: Honestly I'm lost. It seems you are creating a new list with a copy of the values of `ap` and `d`, which is exactly what you should be doing. But, from your previous comment, is `model.estimate` asynchronous? Where are you performing your estimate? I guess your execution should wait until it is finished... but anyway this should not be the reason for your problem, since you are actually creating a new list. Maybe if you could post more details. Thanks.